# I'm using listView but the Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. keep occuring at //1 . i'm beginner in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development

```
     Center(                     //1
       child: ListView(
          children:const [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.map),
              title: Text('map'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
              title: Text('phone'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
              title: Text('album'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
     ),
```

Please explain me why this error has occured.This is the error Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is going to work for you but try it.I would recommend you to not use ListView but ListView.builder,Just follow the next example.

```
//First create these lists.
List<String> _titles = [
'map',
'phone',
'album',
];

List<IconData> _icons = [
Icons.map,
Icons.phone,
Icons.album,
];
```

Then return ListView.builder like this.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _titles.length,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        _titles[index],
      ),
      leading: Icon(
        _icons[index],
      ),
    );
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code and there's no error at all. i think it might be other than that listview is causing the error. try to check your debug console message

this is the code I tried

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: const [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.map),
              title: Text('map'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
              title: Text('phone'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
              title: Text('album'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

and the code work without any error/problem